# ubuntu 22.04 xscreensaver not working

Tags: 22.04, lock-screen, wayland, xscreensaver

On ubuntu 22.04 the xscreensaver was unable to lock the screen.
I executed "xscreensaver-command -lock", its returned "xscreensaver-command: locking not enabled."
However, the ~/.xscreensaver indicate lock was enabled.
grep -w lock ~/.xscreensaver
lock: True

I started Xscreensaver manually, it returned the following message
xscreensaver: 21:49:08: locking is disabled (Cannot lock securely under Wayland)

Please help
Thanks

Comment: It appears that `xscreensaver` does not work with Wayland, Canonical's X replacement. File a bug: `ubuntu-bug wayland`.

Answer (score 1):

It needs to use the Xorg server and not Wayland.
Change to Xorg during login